# Bash Parsing JSON name after sorting

Tags: json, bash

I'm trying to get the most recent (highest number prefix) CacheClusterId from my Elasticache using the AWS CLI in order to put it into a Chef recipe. This is what I've got so far:

```
aws elasticache describe-cache-clusters --region us-east-1 | grep CacheClusterId | sort -t : -rn
```

Which produces:

```
"CacheClusterId": "xy112-elasticache"
"CacheClusterId": "xy111-elasticache"
"CacheClusterId": "xy110-elasticache"
"CacheClusterId": "xy109-elasticache"
"CacheClusterId": "xy-elasticache"
```

How can I isolate just the "xy112-elasticache" portion (minus quotes)? Having read the man page for sort, I feel like it requires a `-k` option, but I haven't been able to work out the particulars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since first part is same for all I will just cut them and take id part in following way:

```
aws elasticache describe-cache-clusters --region us-east-1 | grep CacheClusterId | cut -d'"' -f4
```

Comment: Interesting. Can I use cut to grab only the top record as well? It's the only one I am interested in. My output now is the same as above (multiple records) without the CacheClusterId portion and quotes.

Comment: If it is always the top record you can pipe result of cut to `head -n 1`

Answer (score 1):

I think a much better way is handling JSON using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/). To install on Debian:

```
sudo apt-get install jq
```

I don't know exactly what your JSON looks like, but based on [this XML example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeCacheClusters.html#API_DescribeCacheClusters_Examples) response for the `aws elasticache describe-cache-clusters` command, if your JSON response looked like:

```
{ 
  "CacheClusters": [
    { "CacheClusterId": "xy112-elasticache" , ... },
    { "CacheClusterId": "xy111-elasticache" , ... },
    ...
  ]
}
```

then you'd write:

```
aws elasticache describe-cache-clusters --region us-east-1 | jq ".CacheClusters[].CacheClusterId"
```

For the two JSON objects in the array above, it would return:

```
"xy112-elasticache"
"xy111-elasticache"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Gross as it is, I need to run this in Chef as a command to evaluate lazily on all boxes I create, and I'm reluctant to add another dependency, hence the chosen bash route. I'll keep this in mind for future sorting, however! It seems very powerful.

Comment: @Rome_Leader No excuses, use it!

Comment: @Rome_Leader It's extremely powerful! Much better way to handle JSON than to use `sed` or any stream editors; I'm sure you know the famous "parse HTML with Regex" question here on SO, I think similarly of using stream editors to parse data languages.